# Navigation not working

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have simple JSF application. Everything works fine, but not navigation. It behaves like `<navigation-rule>`s were not there. In my faces-config.xml I have some navigation rules like:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/view/party/create/create.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>edit</from-outcome>
    <if>#{partyCreate.partyTypeSearch.code == partyTypeDao.organisation.code}</if>
    <to-view-id>/view/party/create/edit-organisation.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect />
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

But when I click button on `create.xhtml` page, I get the message:

`Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/view/party/create/create.xhtml' for action '#{partyCreate.displayParty}' with outcome 'edit'`

What can be causing it? I have second application where settings are pretty the same, and there navigation works fine. How can I debug to check what is wrong? There are no error messages while initialization etc.

Comment: What if you remove the `<if>` (just for test)? If in vain, what if you remove the `<from-view-id>` as well?

Comment: Ok, it works. There was error in <if> expression. It's a pity it wasn't reported anywhere. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Okay, I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration looks fine. Perhaps the `<if>` condition simply points to wrong property names or returned unexpected property values. To test the one and other, just remove the `<if>` declaration or run a debugger. If in vain, then try to remove the `<from-view-id>` (so that any view source is valid) to exclude it from being the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug it by looking at `NavigationHandler.handleNavigation` method (if is not overridden, in: `javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler`). 
Within that method you can see what is the next action.
In my opinion I think you should leave the logic - i.e. `<if />` - in the Controller which manage that flow.